# How to redirect to the previous page after submission of a form in a block

Tags: 8, uri, redirection

I have a view of nodes of type task.
I created a block with an inline task create form (using form block module)
The block is next to the view on the same page.

Question:
After creating a new task by using the block, it shows the task full node. Instead, I want it to be redirected to the initial page (the views page) where the task was created.

I understand that the block is not aware of the URL, neither is the task create form in it. That is why a return to previous page in for example business rules, does not work.

How can a redirect be accomplished in this case?

---

I created a module with this code, which does not work:

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */


function yc_noderedirect_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

if ($form_id == 'node_task_form' || $form_id == 'node_article_form') {

    $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
    $form_state->setRedirect($current_path);

  }
}
```

Comment: For the previous page you set a destination query parameter. Or do you mean the current page where the block form is placed? Then add a custom submit handler in a form alter hook and redirect when submitting `$form_state->setRedirect('<current>');`.

Comment: Both can be connected when a destination parameter is already set, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250465/how-to-force-a-redirect-override-the-destination-query-string-in-the-url

Comment: <current> only works in a twig template right? Anyhow, please have a look at my addtion to my question, thanks!

Comment: `setRedirect()` expects a route name and `<current>` is a route name. You need two functions, the form alter hook where you add the custom submit and in this callback you put the redirect, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/234612/redirect-node-form-to-view-after-submit